# how to log date and time in internal memory Mbed using a Nucleo Target Board.

Tags: c++, c, mbed

I came across this question and i was wondering how possible could this be done especially with time and date, being able to log date and time in internal memory and with a minimum of at least 100 past records should be held in memory. i would appreciate it very much if someone could explain this to me or even much better give me an in-sight on how this can be done in C/C++ programming. i would appreciate it if the scolding is at a minimal as i am really eager to know how this can be done and really would like to learn more about this thank you.

Comment: Does the microcontroller include EEPROM? If not, you may be able to emulate EEPROM using the internal Flash memory. Which particular Nucleo board are you planning to use?

Comment: Am planning on using ST F429 Nucleo Target Board @DavidCollins

Comment: I don't think that board has EEPROM. So your options would be either external EEPROM via I2C or emulating EEPROM using Flash.
It does at least have an RTC (Real-Time Clock) though - so generating timestamps should be relatively straightforward.